# Unable to download the recorded video as MP4 in Firefox while what is OK in other browsers like Safari or Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I managed to code in HTML to record videos, which can work in Safari and Edge, but when I test them in **Firefox**, I can only download **webm** instead of **MP4**.
After searching something info, I find the process of MP4 is different from that of wav. Thus, I am there to seek for help.If you need more info, please just inform me~
Any idea would be appreciated !

## record codes:

```
function startRecording() {
            clearRecordedData();
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
                .then((stream) => {
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, recorderOptions);

                    const liveCamera = document.getElementById('liveCamera');
                    liveCamera.srcObject = stream;
                    
                    liveCamera.muted = true;

                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                        if (event.data.size > 0) {
                            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
                        }
                    };

                    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                        recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'video/mp4' }); 

                        console.log(recordedBlob);
                        console.log(recordedBlob.type);


                        recordedVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
                        enableButtons(['startRecord', 'saveRecord', 'playRecord']);
                        disableButtons(['stopRecord']);
                    };

                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    recordedTime = 0;
                    updateRecordedTime();
                    disableButtons(['startRecord']);
                    enableButtons(['stopRecord']);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('getUserMedia error:', error);
                });
        }
```

## save codes:

```
        function saveRecording() {
            if (recordedBlob) {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                var sourceValue = urlParams.get('source');
                a.download = sourceValue + '.mp4';

                console.log(recordedBlob);
                console.log(a);

                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }
        }
```

I try to download the recorded video as MP4 in Firefox but failed ,turn out to be webm.